# jQuery fade in / out in sequence

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity, fade

I am trying to make a set of square divs (".block") fade out when one is clicked, to be replaced by a larger div ("#container"), which fades in as soon as they fade out. This works fine:

```
$('.block').animate({opacity:0},400,'swing',function(){ $('#container").fadeIn();});
```

I use "animate" here because I don't want the space occupied by the blocks to collapse when they fade out (which would happen if I used fadeOut).

The '#container' div has a close button, which when clicked is supposed to fade out the container and fade the blocks back in again. Here's the problem: when the close button is clicked, the container fades out ok, but the new blocks appear very suddenly, as if they're not waiting for the container to close first. Code:

```
$('#container').fadeOut(400,function(){ $('.block').animate({opacity:100},400,'swing');});
```

Comment: Change `opacity: 100` to `opacity: 1`, that should fix it. The css opacity property is a decimal number between 0 and 1, and when you animate it to 100 it reaches 1 fairly quickly :)

Comment: $('.block').animate({opacity:0},400,'swing',function(){ $('#container').fadeIn();});

Comment: @sasi judging by what OP describes it seems like that's just a typo in the answer and not the actual problem.

Comment: OP, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#container')` not closed properly..

```
$('.block').animate({opacity:0},400,'swing',function(){ $('#container').fadeIn();});
```